# Set Title in Tab childs

Tags: android

How can I change a title from tab child?
I tried a simple setTitle(...) but it won't work.

(from the parent tab activity, it does, however...)

thanks, 
Ori

Comment: how do you created the tabs? and is each tab a tabactivity?

Comment: I create one tab activity and 3 regular activities and then I add them to the tab activity (tabHost.addTab(...))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I got it to work this way:
In the TabActvitiy, override:
onChildTitleChanged().

This method is called when a child activity invoking setTitle(). from there you can change the title of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API to modify the tabs once created -- sorry!

Comment: and what about the progress bar? can a child tab affect that?

Comment: true but you can still change the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

I know that if you're adding tabs dynamically you can use ts.setIndicator("MY TAB!");

...
like so:

```
myTabHost = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.th_set_menu_tabhost); 
myTabHost.setup();

ls1 = new ListView(Main_screen.this);       
TabSpec ts1 = myTabHost.newTabSpec("TAB_TAG_1");
ts1.setIndicator("Tab1");
ts1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
    public View createTabContent(String tag)
    {                                   
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main_screen.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"item1","item2","item3"});
        ls1.setAdapter(adapter);    
        return ls1;
    }       
});
myTabHost.addTab(ts1);
```

*here's the xml if you need it*

```
 <TabWidget 
      android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="64dip" />

 <FrameLayout 
      android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:paddingTop="64dip">  

      <ListView
          android:id = "@+id/danhsach"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

 </FrameLayout>
```